# Tkinter: ¿Cómo ajustar ventana Entry y elegir ubicación de Radiobuttons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy usando la librería Tkinter para desarrollar una pequeña ventana donde se permita la entrada de ciertos valores, pero quisiera ajustar el tamaño de las pantallas generadas por Entry para que la que se usa para el nombre sea mas grande, y la que se usa para edad mas pequeño. Ademas quisiera que los botones de Si y No aparecieran uno al costado del otro y no debajo como se muestra. Adjunto el código que estoy usando y como esta quedando mi ventana.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title("Inicio Sistema de Monitoreo")
root.resizable(1,1) 
root.geometry("350x250") 

varOpcion=IntVar()

miFrame=Frame(root, width=350, height=250)
miFrame.pack()

mensaje=Label(miFrame,text="Ingrese los datos del paciente: ")
mensaje.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

cuadroNombre=Entry(miFrame)
cuadroNombre.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
cuadroNombre=Entry(miFrame)
cuadroNombre.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
cuadroNombre=Entry(miFrame)
cuadroNombre.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
cuadroNombre=Entry(miFrame)
cuadroNombre.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

nombreLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Nombre completo: ")
nombreLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="n", padx=5, pady=5)
nombreLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Edad: ")
nombreLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="n", padx=5, pady=5)
nombreLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Telefono: ")
nombreLabel.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="n", padx=5, pady=5)
nombreLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Nombre: ")
nombreLabel.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="n", padx=5, pady=5)

nombreLabel=Label(miFrame, text="¿Es paciente de riesgo?")
nombreLabel.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="n", padx=5, pady=5)

button1=Radiobutton(root, text="Si", variable=varOpcion, value=1).pack()
button2=Radiobutton(root, text="No", variable=varOpcion, value=2).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen, quisiera saber como ajustar el tamaño del Entry de nombre y edad, y como colocar las opciones de Si y No la derecha de la pregunta y no abajo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ademas quisiera que los botones de Si y No aparecieran uno al costado del otro

Eso sería posible si usaras otro administrador de geometría en tu app, `grid()` es poco eficiente ya que no ofrece presición y `pack()` no ofrece opciones. Entonces esta ubicación de varios widgets en una misma linea solo es posible con `place()`, debido a que este usa porcentajes de los pixeles totales de la ventana.

```
button1 = Radiobutton(framePlace, text="Si", variable=varOpcion, value=1)
button1.place(relx = 0.515, rely = 0.1)
```

En este ejemplo, sea `relx` 51,5% de los pixeles (horizontalmente) totales, y rely 10% verticalmente.

**Alineación multi-widget**

Veamos un ejemplo donde intentamos alinear tres widgets en una misma linea:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("App") 
root.geometry("200x50") 

framePlace = Frame(root, width = 200, height = 50)
framePlace.pack()

nombreLabel = Label(framePlace, text="¿Es feliz?")
nombreLabel.pack()
nombreLabel.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.15)

button1 = Radiobutton(framePlace, text="Si")
button1.place(relx = 0.4, rely = 0.15)
button2 = Radiobutton(framePlace, text="No")
button2.place(relx = 0.6, rely = 0.15)

root.mainloop()
```

**Nota:** `place()` tiene como punto de referencia el frame donde se ubica el widget, en caso de no haberlo tendrá como referencia la ventana inicial.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> quisiera ajustar el tamaño de las pantallas generadas por Entry para
> que la que se usa para el nombre sea mas grande

El mismo administrador de geometría `place()` es capaz de modificar el tamaño del mismo widget:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("App") 
root.geometry("200x50") 

framePlace = Frame(root, width = 200, height = 50)
framePlace.pack()

texto = Entry(framePlace)
texto.place(relx = 0.2,rely = 0.2,relwidth = 0.6,relheight = 0.5)

root.mainloop()
```

Las propiedades `relwidth` y `relheight`definen las dimensiones del widget. En particular `relheight` solo el largo del widget, no el tamaño de la fuente. Lo recomendable es también cambiar el tamaño de la fuente.

```
texto = Entry(framePlace, font = "Arial 15")
```

Se obtiene:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Adjunto el código que estoy usando y como esta quedando mi ventana.

Viendo tu código, te recomendaría cambiar el administrador de geometría de todos los widgets a `place()`. Toma en cuenta que no puedes usar `place()` y `grid()` en un mismo frame.

Espero te haya servido de algo.

Comment: Entiendo, lo estoy probando y me funciona justo como quería, muchas gracias!